# Is there a way to make a property runtime-only in .NET?

Tags: .net, function, properties, user-controls, runtime

I have a UserControl, I want to create a property that will be accessible only at run-time, and not design time. Is that possible with properties, or should I create a function instead?

Comment: Would you show your solution with function? I can't understand your problem.

Comment: I just want a property to be invisible in WinForms designer, because it makes sense only when the program executes.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this.  Why do you care if its visible within the WinForms designer.

Answer (score 5):

It just takes attributes.  You'll probably want to use [DesignTimeSerializationVisibility] so the value of the property doesn't get persisted in the InitializeComponent() method.  And [Browsable] so it isn't visible in the VS Properties window.  Like this:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int DontPersistAndDontEdit {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try applying a combination of these attributes:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Browsable(false)]
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use what .NET offers for designer support. :)

Comment: This isn't very helpful.  There's no point in hiding the property from IntelliSense.  And [DesignTimeVisible] can only apply to a class, not a property.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the `DesignTimeOnly` attribute from my answer. Whether or not the property should be hidden from intellisense is up to the OP, but that's why I said to apply a combination of the attributes listed above.